# CLion Windows injectable library

Tags: c++, dll, clion, inject

I am trying to make a library that will attach a cmd window to a process and print text in it. I'm using CLion and MinGW.

When I inject the dll to a process (using Extreme Injector) I get this error:

[image: picture].

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(framework)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCE_FILES library.cpp library.h)
add_library(framework SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and `library.h`:

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_H
#define FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_H
void hello();
#endif
```

and finally, the `library.cpp`:

```
#include "library.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

void hello() {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    printf("the dll injected!\n");
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE instance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)hello, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```